# AOSP native client bind to java service

Tags: android, c++, native, bind, android-source

We have a native client process that we want to be able to call `bindService` in to bind to a java service that we don't want running all the time if not being used. Bound services allows us to utilize lazy starting so we aren't up and running constantly and will manage refcount so that the service will clean itself up when no more clients are using it.

There doesn't seem to be any aidl calls we can use that allow us to call `bindService`. Just `getService`, `checkService`, etc. what's exposed through `ServiceManager` or `ActivityManager` on native. Is there another way to get around this or an alternative solution that solves this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You could always fall back to creating a java bound service that instantiates your native service in `onBind`.

Comment: The service is already java. The client is native. My question is in regards to how a native client can bind regardless of whether the service is native or java.